# TortoiseHG phases are wrong

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, kiln

For some reason TortoiseHG stopped considering my pushed changesets as having a phase of `public`; it's keeping them as "default."

Is there any way to force TortoiseHG to "sync up" with the remote repository, and get this straight?

Is there a way in Kiln?

[image]

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, shouldn't the phases be marked as public once they've been merged to the main branch?

Comment: @Eddie - I'm not sure.  I haven't yet merged my branch back to the main line, so I can't confirm that this is the case.  I was just trying to figure out why pushes into the branch itself weren't switching to "public"

Comment: Turns out the repo we have been working on was actually a branch repository, which I didn't even realise was a thing. I thought you just meant branches within one repository. Anyway there was a button in the repo settings that let us upgrade our branch repo to be a central one and now the phases are correct again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this was a recent change in Kiln.  As of version 3, pushed changes **to a branch repository** will show up as draft if they're not a part of the main, central repository from which the branch was created.